# Why am I getting errors when trying to use tensorflow in RStudio? Do I need to edit my path?

Tags: r, tensorflow, rstudio

I'm hoping that someone on here might be able to help with a problem I'm having... I have been trying to install tensorflow into RStudio (using these instructions: https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/installation/) for a couple weeks but keep coming up against an error, which I haven't been able to solve using recommendations by other users with other similar problems on this site. In fact, this usually leads to more errors. I operate on Windows 10 and have versions: R 4.0.0, RStudio 1.3.959, Python 3.8 + Anaconda. I am **very new** to R and RStudio and have not yet used Python, but I have a feeling that the problem may be something to do with the path...

This is the whole process from start to finish:

```
> install.packages("tensorflow")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Jodie/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/tensorflow_2.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 143984 bytes (140 KB)
downloaded 140 KB

package ‘tensorflow’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Jodie\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcnUyxX\downloaded_packages

> library(tensorflow)
> install_tensorflow()
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

# All requested packages already installed.

Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow==2.2.0 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.12.0 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: astunparse==1.6.3 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (3.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: gast==0.3.3 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: protobuf>=3.8.0 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (3.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.29.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wheel>=0.26; python_version >= "3" in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (0.34.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: absl-py>=0.7.0 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: keras-preprocessing>=1.1.0 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tensorflow-estimator<2.3.0,>=2.2.0 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wrapt>=1.11.1 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-pasta>=0.1.8 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scipy==1.4.1; python_version >= "3" in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.8.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (47.1.1.post20200604)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.6.0.post3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-auth<2,>=1.6.3 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.25.9)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (2020.4.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: rsa<4.1,>=3.1.4 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (4.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (4.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8" in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\jodie\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"->markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (3.1.0)

Installation complete.


Restarting R session...

> library(tensorflow)
> tf$constant("Hellow Tensorflow")
Error: Installation of TensorFlow not found.

Python environments searched for 'tensorflow' package:
 C:\Users\Jodie\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\python.exe

You can install TensorFlow using the install_tensorflow() function.
```

Is it that R is looking for tensorflow in the wrong place and I just need to change my path? If I use reticulate described here:https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/issues/144 I get the same error with the following messgae:

```
In addition: Warning message:
Python 'C:\Users\Jodie\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-tensorflow\python.exe' was requested but 'C:/Users/Jodie/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe' was loaded instead (see reticulate::py_config() for more information)
```

I am hoping to use tensorflow and keras to classify body condition of leopard seals using images, for my MSc research course, so if anyone has any suggestions then it would be extremely helpful, thank you!

Comment: It is python installed in your computer?

Comment: Yes I have python 3.8 installed